# How to Add Icon in cells of a column CListCtrl

Tags: mfc

I have a CListCtrl that shows my data in rows. It has two column. Now i need to add another column that will be actually showing a icon.

```
// set look and feel
listCtrl.SetExtendedStyle(listCtrl.GetExtendedStyle() | columnStyles);
```

Adding row items as below :

```
for (const auto dataValue : dataTable)
{
    int rowIndex = listCtrl.GetItemCount();
    listCtrl.InsertItem(rowIndex, dataValue.at(0).c_str());
    for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex < listCtrl.GetHeaderCtrl()->GetItemCount(); ++colIndex)
    {
        listCtrl.SetItemText(rowIndex, colIndex, dataValue.at(colIndex).c_str());
    }
}
```

I added a new column that will contain the icons for the rows.

I can not getting proper idea how to add icon in the cells of the added column. Consider it's added in first column.

Please suggest.

Comment: Uh, call the `SetItem` function. The overload with the `nImage` parameter will work: set it to the index of the image in your CListCtrl's ImageList. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3wdxcd3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new column, as the image is displayed in the left of the first column (Given your text I assume you are using the LVS_REPORT style).

You need to have a member image list with same count of images as items of your list. So on your list's derived class, add a member:

```
CImageList m_ImageList;
```

Then on your list's `OnCreate` function:

```
m_ImageList.Create(32, 32, ILC_COLOR24, numberOfEnableParts, 1);
m_ImageList.SetImageCount(n);

for (int i = 0; i< n; i++)
{

    if(InsertItem(n, sText) != -1)
    {
         //set text of columns with SetItemText
         //...
         // don't know if you use a icon or a bitmap; next line I did it for the second case
         m_ImageList->Replace(n, CBitmap::FromHandle(hBmp), (CBitmap*)NULL);

        //then, associate the item with its own image of the image list

        LVITEM lvi;
        lvi.iItem= i;
        lvi.iSubItem= 0;
        lvi.mask =  LVIF_IMAGE;
        lvi.iImage= i;
        SetItem(&lvi);

    }
}


SetImageList(m_ImageList, LVSIL_SMALL);
```